# Can I use tw_cli migrate to grow a RAID10 unit where the drives for that unit were each replaced one by one with larger drives?

Tags: hardware-raid, 3ware

Can I use tw_cli migrate to grow a RAID10 unit where the drives for that unit were each replaced one by one with larger drives? (And the array was rebuilt after each replacement operation.) I am assuming the command to run is as follows:

tw_cli /c0/u0 migrate type=raid10 disk=0-3

The disks in question are 0-3 of course.

Comment: Which controller do you have?